# How do I describe optimal policy (pi*) of bellman's equation?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I tried to find what is pi* in many resources like [this link](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node35.html). But, I can not find what is pi*. Is V* is same as V_pi*?

[Screenshot of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ0oO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

π* is used to represent the "optimal policy". V* and Q* are optimal value functions. Optimal value functions lead to optimal policies.

Have a look at the Section 4.6 at https://web.fe.up.pt/~eol/schaefer/diplom/ReinforcementLearning.htm